# Unexpected Identifier in ForEach and for .. of

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I have this code :

```
var maneuver = {
    "diceOnHand" : 0,
    "rollResult" : [],

    "diceRoll" : function(diceNumber) {
        dicePool.action.take(diceNumber);
        this.diceOnHand += diceNumber;

        for (i = 1; i <= this.diceOnHand; i++) {
            this.rollResult.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1);
        }

        this.rollResult.ForEach(function(entry) {
            if (entry > 2 and entry < 6) {
                //GO TO STRIKE POOL
                dicePool.strike.add(1);
            } else
            if (entry == 6) {
                //GO TO CHARGE POOL
                dicePool.charge.add(1);
            }
        });
        /*
        for (j of this.rollResult) {
            if (j > 2 and j < 6) {
                //GO TO STRIKE POOL
                dicePool.strike.add(1);
            } else
            if (j == 6) {
                //GO TO CHARGE POOL
                dicePool.charge.add(1);
            }
        }*/ 
    }
}
```

Variable `entry` and `j` in the `for` loops are always treated as "Unexpected Identifier". I wonder why are they treated as such even though they should be legal identifiers afaik.

Comment: The syntax of your loop is invalid... you need [for in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Comment: may be you want `for (j in this.rollResult)`?

Comment: `for .. of` is a [legit syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/id/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of). I suppose I could use `for .. in`, but I've been wondering about this issue.

Comment: @vp_arth Even using `for .. in` still gives me "Unexpected Identifier".

Comment: `j > 2 and j < 6` => `j > 2 && j < 6`

Comment: @vp_arth you're my hero T_T Could you put in as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JS has not `and` logical operator. Use `&&`.

`j > 2 && j < 6`

Answer (score 0):

what vp_arth said and i see another mistake here:

```
if (entry > 2 and entry < 6) {
            //GO TO STRIKE POOL
            dicePool.strike.add(1);
        } else
```

should be :

```
if (entry > 2  && entry < 6) {
            //GO TO STRIKE POOL
            dicePool.strike.add(1);
        } else
```

For further reading, check this : 
[JavaScript Logical Operators](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)